# adding new tab manually and changing focus to it

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

So, in my `<tabset>` I have 3 sets of tabs. I first have three static tabs, then N dynamic tabs, and then an "add tab."

[image]

When you click on the add tab, you get a small input with which you can select your "layer type"

[image]

And when you select one, it adds a new tab of that type.

[image]

What I'm trying to do is make it so it selects that new tab, and deselects the "add tab." I've tried keeping an array of currently active tabs and checking every tab manually for "active", but for some reason, it always thinks the last tab is active, even when I manually set it's active to `false` and splice a new one into the array with `true`.

Any thoughts on how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I essentially had to do was remove the "funny stuff" from the tabs. That means no select menus, no weird controls that can take focus, etc. When those went away, my problems with tab focusing did as well.

Answer (score 0):

In the tab set an active flag

```
        <tab header="..." active="tabs.tab1"....>
```

In your controller setup a map of the tabs

```
        $scope.theTabs = {'tab1':false, 'tab2':false };
```

To make a tab active or inactive you just need to set the flag to true/false

```
        $scope.theTabs['tabl1'] = true;
```

Works great.

Comment: Theoretically this would also work with keeping the "active" flag in an array, right? That's what I previously tried, to no avail. I've also tried to make it an array of objects where they look like this: `{active: true}` and checking `myArr[index].active`

Comment: Are you setting the active= in the <tab... itself?   That is the important part here.

Comment: Yes. However, I'm changing it from a `$scope.$watch`.